# Could not load dbcapi library in Rails 6.0.6 production mode

Tags: ruby, passenger, sqlanywhere, passenger-apache

I'm working on a web project, which connects to a SQLAnywhere version 17 database. I'm using Ruby version 2.6.2 and Rails 6.0.6 to run the app.

I've already set the SQLAnywhere environment variables, hosted in the following script:

```
. /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/sa_config.sh
```

In the development environment it works without apparent problems, but in the production environment it throws me the following error:

```
LoadError (Could not load SQLAnywhere DBCAPI library):
```

I've already tried setting the various bash script manually, but it still didn't work. What else could I try?

The gems that depend on these libraries are the following:

```
gem 'sequel'
gem 'sqlanywhere'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas?. Please, I do not know what to do next...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, loading the definition of the variables in the configuration file in two locations:

```
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default/ruby
/etc/rvmrc
```